# Exponential forecasting with non-constant variance

Tags: stationarity, exponential-smoothing, anomaly-detection

I want to use exponential forecasting to detect outliers, but my data are  means of samples of different sizes. The series was formed by taking the average, every five minutes, of measurements observed within that window. The actual number of observations varies from 1 to 50,000, depending on time of day and other factors. Assuming constant variance in the underlying data, the sample means do not have constant variance. In fact, A number of "outliers" in the series, as detected by the exponential smoother, occur in time chunks with low sample counts and are probably due to random variation -- not anomalous behaviour.

Does anyone know how to adapt the exponential smoother, and especially its error bounds on the predicted forecasts, to take into account non-constant variance? I know the number of items in each 5 minute chunk, but I don't have access to the raw data themselves.